# Can I just send Object Body using java 11 HttpClient using Custom Body Publisher?

Tags: java, rest, http, httpclient

I would like to know that I can send Object itself as a body without converting them to String using `BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody)` like below

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI("http://localhost:8080/api/test"))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .build();
```

According to official doc [http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~prappo/8087113/javadoc.02/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#fromFile-java.nio.file.Path-](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eprappo/8087113/javadoc.02/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#fromFile-java.nio.file.Path-)
There's no method that I can use to just send the object as body.
Request bodies are sent using one of the request processor implementations below provided in `HttpRequest`, **or else a custom implementation can be used.**

- `[fromByteArray(byte[])](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~prappo/8087113/javadoc.02/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#fromByteArray-byte:A-)` from byte array
- `[fromByteArrays(Iterator)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~prappo/8087113/javadoc.02/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#fromByteArrays-java.util.Iterator-)` from an iterator of byte arrays
- `[fromFile(Path)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~prappo/8087113/javadoc.02/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#fromFile-java.nio.file.Path-)` from the file located at the given Path
- `[fromString(String)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~prappo/8087113/javadoc.02/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#fromString-java.lang.String-)` from a String
- `[fromInputStream(InputStream)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~prappo/8087113/javadoc.02/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#fromInputStream-java.io.InputStream-)` request body from InputStream
- `[noBody()](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~prappo/8087113/javadoc.02/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html#noBody--)` no request body is sent

Can I customize BodyPublishers?
I would like to use java 11 httpClient and want to send Object as a body like org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate's `postForEntity()`

Comment: Which content type do you want to send?

Comment: I would like to send json. ```ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); MyDto myDto= objectMapper.readValue(new URL("file:src/main/resources/myjsonfile.json"), MyDto .class);
String requestBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myDto);
return requestBody;``` but I wanna skip the part ```writeValueAsString``` and just use myDto Object

Comment: Implement and use your own `HttpRequest.BodyPublisher` that wraps that JSON serializing code. Spring works by implementing an `HttpMessageConverter` that does the same (for use by the `RestTemplate`).